# Найти селектор кода элемента страницы

Tags: html

Настраиваю автоматизацию в антидетект браузере AdsPower. Нужно, чтобы робот кликал на рандомный сайт из поисковой выдачи гугл. Но не могу определить селектор этого самого рандомного сайта. Помогите, пожалуйста[image: на скриншоте пример того на что должен кликать робот]

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('#center_col a')[x]`

Пробуй так, там где х замени на рандомное число, но не больше чем длина масива